# R, ggplot — customize my barplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

This is my datastructure:

```
      Accession Source   Name NucSource Order   color Counts   Normalized
1          Str1    Our   Str1        ch     1 #1C9099  66827 2.318683e-01
2  Str1_plasmid    Our   Str1        pl     2 #1C9099     26 9.021169e-05
3          Str2    Our   Str2        ch     3 #1C9099 288211 1.000000e+00
4  Str2_plasmid    Our   Str2        pl     4 #1C9099  71858 2.493243e-01
5          Str3    Our   Str3        ch     5 #1C9099  40600 1.408690e-01
6  Str3_plasmid    Our   Str3        pl     6 #1C9099  25266 8.766494e-02
7          Str4   NCBI   Str4        ch     7 #A6BDDB  21339 7.403951e-02
8          Str5   NCBI   Str5        ch     8 #A6BDDB  37776 1.310706e-01
9          Str6   NCBI   Str6        ch     9 #A6BDDB   3596 1.247697e-02
10         Str7   NCBI   Str7        ch    10 #A6BDDB   5384 1.868076e-02
11 Str7_plasmid   NCBI   Str7        pl    11 #A6BDDB  40903 1.419203e-01
12         Str8   NCBI   Str8        ch    12 #A6BDDB   8948 3.104670e-02
13         Str9   NCBI   Str9        ch    13 #A6BDDB  16557 5.744750e-02
14 Str9_plasmid   NCBI   Str9        pl    14 #A6BDDB   3738 1.296966e-02
15        Str10   NCBI  Str10        ch    15 #A6BDDB  10067 3.492927e-02
16        Str11   NCBI  Str11        ch    16 #A6BDDB   7306 2.534948e-02
17        Str12   NCBI  Str12        ch    17 #A6BDDB  10313 3.578281e-02
```

I run the following code on it:

```
p<-ggplot(data=myData, aes(x=Name, y=Normalized, fill=Source)) +
  theme_few() +
  xlab("Strain") + ylab("Normalized counts") +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", aes(fill=myData$Source), colour="black", position="dodge") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.4)) +
  geom_text(aes(label=myData$NucSource), vjust=-0.5) +
  theme(legend.position="right") +
  scale_fill_manual(values=as.character(color.convert$color)[2:3])

print(p)
```

And this is the result:
[image]

What I would like to have now, is that for examples like "Str1" where I have "chr" and "pl" the two bars should be horizontally next to each other (Also for "Str2", "Str3", "Str7", "Str8"). But for cases like "Str4" where I have only "ch" there should be only one bar.
So the bars should not be on top of each other but horizontally arranged.

**EDIT -- dput(head(myData, 20)):**

> structure(list(Accession = structure(c(16L, 17L, 12L, 13L, 14L,  15L,
>   1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L), .Label = c("CP000517", 
>   "CP002081", "CP002427", "CP002429", "CP002430_plasmid", "CP003799", 
>   "CP009907", "CP009908_plasmid", "CP011386", "CP012381", "CP016827", 
>   "FAM22155", "FAM22155_plasmid", "FAM8105", "FAM8105_plasmid", 
>   "FAM8627", "FAM8627_plasmid"), class = "factor"), Source =
>   structure(c(2L,  2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
>   1L, 1L, 1L ), .Label = c("NCBI", "Our"), class = "factor"), Name =
>   structure(c(1L,  1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 9L,
>   10L, 11L,  12L), .Label = c("FAM8627", "FAM22155", "FAM8105", "DPC
>   4571",  "CNRZ32", "H9", "H10", "R0052", "KLDS1.8701", "MB2-1",
>   "CAUH18",  "D76"), class = "factor"), NucSource = structure(c(1L, 2L,
>   1L,  2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label =
>   c("ch",  "pl"), class = "factor"), Order = 1:17, color =
>   structure(c(1L,  1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,
>   2L, 2L, 2L ), .Label = c("#1C9099", "#A6BDDB", "#ECE2F0"), class =
>   "factor"), 
>       Counts = c(66827L, 26L, 288211L, 71858L, 40600L, 25266L, 
>       21339L, 37776L, 3596L, 5384L, 40903L, 8948L, 16557L, 3738L, 
>       10067L, 7306L, 10313L), Normalized = c(0.231868318697066, 
>       9.02116851889761e-05, 1, 0.249324279781133, 0.140869016102786, 
>       0.0876649399224873, 0.0740395057787524, 0.131070639219183, 
>       0.0124769699976753, 0.0186807581945172, 0.141920329203257, 
>       0.0310466984258061, 0.0574474950643799, 0.0129696645860151, 
>       0.0349292705691316, 0.0253494835381023, 0.0357828118982273
>       )), .Names = c("Accession", "Source", "Name", "NucSource",  "Order", "color", "Counts", "Normalized"), row.names = c(NA,  17L),
>   class = "data.frame")

Comment: Could you please `dput(head(myData, 20))` and copy/paste it into your question?  This makes it far easier for us to help you rather than having to create your data frame they way you provided it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]You need to `dodge` on a different column than `fill`:

```
ggplot(data=myData, aes(x = Name, y = Normalized, dodge = NucSource, fill = Source)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = NucSource), vjust = -0.5) +
  geom_col(colour="black", position="dodge") +
  labs(x = "Strain", y = "Normalized counts") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.4),
        legend.position = "right")
```

PS: I changed some bits, because I was not sure which theme or extra packages you are using.

Comment: Nice! Now, how can make the bars with only "ch" the same width than if I have "ch" and "pl". And how can I make "ch" and "pl" appearing on top of the respective bars and not in the center?

Comment: I would recommend using `position = position_dodge()` in the bar and the text. This way OP can set `position = position_dodge(width = 0.9)` to center the text.  Also `geom_col()` is short form for `geom_bar(stat = "identity")`.